# Ingresar x numeros y que solo se muestre los mayores a 20

Tags: c

Quería saber de alguna manera hacer esto utilizando "for" "printf" "scan" y algun "if".

Me quedé en:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int i,n,valor,mayores;

main()
{
    Printf("Ingresar x cantidad de numeros, solo se mostraran los mayores a 20\n");
    Printf("Cuantos numeros desea ingresar:      ");
    Scanf("%d",&n); fflush(stdin);

    For(i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {
        Printf("Numero %d :   ",i);
        Scanf("%d",&valor); fflush(stdin);
```

---

¿Cómo hago para que me tire luego los enteros que escribi mayores a 20?

Comment: Esto se parece más a C que C++

Comment: Es completamente [tag:c] @aeportugal (salvo por las funciones en mayúsculas, eso no se que es).

Comment: Pero si ya lo tienes. Pon un "if" que mire si el número leído con "scan" es mayor que 20 y en caso de serlo utiliza un "print" para mostrarlo.

Comment: Pense que puse C .. error mio! Con respecto al planteo del problema, al poner el if solo me sale el ultimo valor mas grande que ingreso, quisiera que me aparezcan todos los ingresados mayores a 20. Saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una alternativa es con un arreglo dinámico, para esto necesitas la libreria de stdlib, ya que para un array de este tipo usamos un puntero, y ya después de elegir el total de número le damos el tamaño al array con "n".

Al final recorremos y sólo imprimes los mayores a 20.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
  int i, n, *valores, mayores, valor;
    printf("Ingresar x cantidad de numeros, solo se mostraran los mayores a 20\n");
    printf("Cuantos numeros desea ingresar:      ");
    scanf("%i",&n); 
    //Asiganoms el tamaño
    valores = (int *) calloc(n, sizeof(int));
    fflush(stdin);
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++){
        printf("Numero %i :   ",i);
        scanf("%d",&valor);
        valores[i] = valor;
        fflush(stdin);
    }
    //Impresión del array dinámico
    for(i = 1; i < n ; i++){
      if(valores[i] > 20){
        printf("\n%i",valores[i]);
      }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, me sirvio! Ahora a leer sobre el tema. Saludos